# Como posso contar campos que são NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou utilizando essa query:
Gostaria de saber como posso contar esses campos que nao possuem registros. Aqui retorna 0. Mas tenho alguns registros nulos. O que faço?

```
SELECT DataFim, COUNT(DataFim) AS QTD FROM AtivacaoGuincho
GROUP BY DataFim
HAVING DataFim is  null
```

Comment: Se puder, experimente `SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(DataFim) AS qtd` e me comente se funciona.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS QTD FROM AtivacaoGuincho
WHERE DataFim is  null
```

Já que o Marlon tocou no assunto da contabilização das linhas posso melhorar um
pouco mais essa resposta e entrar num assunto que é quase uma curiosidade.

O count é basicamente usado dessa maneira acima. Solicito que contabilize todas linhas ONDE a DATAFIM é nula.

Mas poderia fazer assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL, COUNT(DATAFIM) AS DTFIM FROM AtivacaoGuincho
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E teria algo assim: tenho 1884 linhas na tabela e 50 linhas onde DATAFIM é nula.

E claro, poderia ter tantos counts quantos quisesse no meu select.

Comment: esse me retorna 2. É o correto

Answer (score 6):

Faltou a cláusula where corretamente..

```
SELECT COUNT(DataFim) AS QTD 
FROM AtivacaoGuincho
WHERE DataFim is  null
```

EDIT:

Desculpe pelo erro de `Ctrl+c/Ctrl+v`, o correto é:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS QTD 
FROM AtivacaoGuincho
WHERE DataFim is null
```

E pra quem não sabe a diferença entre `Count(*)` e `Count(coluna)` é que:

- `Count(*)` contabiliza todas as linhas sem exceções.
- `Count(coluna)` contabiliza valores da `coluna` que não são *nulos*
  (`null`)

Comment: esse me retona 0

Comment: @Aline, editei a resposta com uma informação que pode ser valiosa pra você :)

Comment: Opa, obrigada moço.

Comment: Awwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww entendi

Comment: Agora sei pq estava me retornando 0...